# When will Ubuntu be getting the new file picker that Gnome got

Tags: gnome, filemanager

I am referring to the infamous filepicker bug that got recently (months ago) fixed on Gnome. Any idea on when we can expect the fix to be used on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an actual bug tracker link, not an OMG link. Comments are transitory.

Comment: @user535733 again, I am not reporting a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, Gnome releases about a month before Ubuntu.

So IF the feature is in Gnome 44
And IF Gnome 44 releases on-time around March 2023
And IF the Ubuntu Desktop Team has the resources to include Gnome 44
Then Ubuntu 23.04 would have it.

So the answer to "when" is perhaps April 2023, but that's not a guarantee. Everything has to work properly for that.